# Internet Explorer and Umbraco

Tags: css, internet-explorer, umbraco

I've been developing my website with Umbraco, and I'm almost finishing the design, and I've been testing my website in both google chrome and firefox. Today I tried with internet explorer and all my images got re-sized in this browser. Any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it? Everything works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, so I cannot really tell how to fix it in IE.

Hope anyone can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing an example page, or maybe some screenshots, it'll be hard to see what the issue is. The front end of Umbraco is all your code though, so it's unlikely that Umbraco is the issue here, it's more likely something used on the page. Can you provide more detail, e.g. what kind of elements are the images? <img>, or background images set by CSS. that sort of thing.

Comment: which javascript library you are using?

Comment: @Tim, here is a example of how it works with Google Chrome (the right way): [Chrome Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/dfg2novp7/)   I have an image with hover effect which displays text when mouseover. Here is how it looks in Internet Explorer: [IE Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/c9bm5lb1t/) The images are with their real size and dont get rezied to fit the div. I tried to use the 100% rule for all the divs. The images are <img>. Thank you very much! This issue only happens in IE, not in Chrome nor Firefox.

Comment: Anyone? I really cannot find what the problem is

Comment: Any kind person can help please?

Comment: Must be a CSS issue. Update the question with details of any jquery library and the snippet of css you are using to show the tiles.

Comment: I just solved the issue. For anyone having the same kind of issue, I added "display: block" in the css and it worked like a charm.